Dynamic SQLAlchemy filter
I am trying to write a dynamic filter for an API that uses SQLAlchemy (python). The front end will pass in optional arguments via query string to the backend and then the python backend should query the database with the filter values. Zero filters should return all rows of users in this case.
Generally: the front end will call my API endpoint with something like this
http://mybackend.com/api?first_name=John&last_name=Doe

The desired backend looks like this in my mind, but maybe this is not the best way to handle things.
def filter_results():
    filter_obj = {
        'first_name' : request.args.get('first_name', null, type=str),
        'last_name' : request.args.get('last_name', null, type=str),
        'city' : request.args.get('city', null, type=str),
        'country' : request.args.get('country', null, type=str),
        'phone' : request.args.get('phone', null, type=int)
    }
    query_string = ''
    for k, v in filter_obj.items():
        if v != null:
            query_string += f'{k} = {v}, '
    query_string.rstrip(', ')
    user_profile = Users.query.filter_by(query_string).all()
    response = users_schema.dump(user_profile)
    return jsonify(response)


I cannot figure out how to do this correctly and now I'm here.
I have tried playing with hardcoding a filter string like the following
filter_string = 'first_name = "John"'
Users.query.filter_by(filter_string).all()

and
from sqlalchemy import text
filter_string = 'first_name = "John"'
Users.query.filter_by(text(filter_string)).all()

But these do not work.
Any ideas on how to implement this would be appreciated.

Does this answer your question?

Yes! That's even better than what I came up with. I just couldn't figure out how to google my problem! Much appreciated.

I figured it out, wWat worked for me:
def filter_results():
    first_name = request.args.get('first_name', '%%', type=str),
    last_name = request.args.get('last_name', '%%', type=str),
    city = request.args.get('city', '%%', type=str),
    country = request.args.get('country', '%%', type=str),
    phone = request.args.get('phone', '%%', type=int)
    # the '%%' is a wildcard and will turn up all results in the column

    # using .ilike() ignores case, so 'foo' == 'Foo' == 'fOo', etc...
    filtered_users = Users.query.filter(Users.first_name.ilike(first_name),
        Users.last_name.ilike(last_name),
        Users.city.ilike(city),
        Users.country.ilike(country),
        Users.phone.ilike(phone)).all()
    response = users_schema.dump(filtered_users)
    return jsonify(response)


You can try to use https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-sqlalchemy-mixins/. You can just create a dict and apply to a query.
